# php pdo transaction commit roolback is not working for multiple insert and update

Tags: php, pdo

Below is my batchinsertUpdate function for inserting and updating bulk data.
I am using transaction,commit and rollback process. But there is no insert or update is working. But when I remove transaction, commit and rollback code its working. But I want run batchinsertupdate function with transaction, commit and rollback.

```
public function batchinsertUpdate ($array, $dbConnection = null) {
        try {
            if ($dbConnection == null) {
                $dbConnection = DatabaseConnectionManager::getConnection ();
            }
            $dbConnection->beginTransaction ();
            $tableName = 'abc1';
            foreach ( $array as $value ) {
                $checkRowInDatabase = $this->checkRowExit( $value1,$value2,$value3,$value4,$value5);
                if ($checkRowInDatabase == '1') {
                    //Here is my update query
                    $result = $sth->execute ();
                } else {
                    //Here is my insert query
                    $result = $sth->execute ();
                }
            }
            $dbConnection->commit ();
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            $dbConnection->rollback ();
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Is there any way to run both insert and update with commit and roolback?
I am also trying $dbConnection->commit (); after insert and update but only one record is inserting. Please suggest me.

Comment: have you tried it without the try...catch block?

Comment: In our coding standard try catch is following.